# Region Monitoring in app terminated state

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, region-monitoring

In my app, I have used CLLocationManager for region monitoring. Region monitoring is working perfectly when the app is in foreground and background. But didEnterRegion delegate is not get fired when the app is manually killed by the user from the app-switcher. Is there any solution for this. I have seen that from iOS 7 app will not wake up when the app is in the terminated state. Do any changes in new iOS version update?

iOS version:11.4

Comment: delegates would not be called in a terminated state. If a user has killed the application, in that case, nothing will work at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But in apple document they said, if the app is suspended when the event occurs, it’s woken up and given a short amount of time (around 10 seconds) to handle the event.

Comment: @Anju Suspended and Terminated are two different states. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: @AlexCornforth Thanks for the reply. I think I am more clear right now, I got a little bit confused with the suspended and terminated state, Thanks a lot.